# rand() function wont work when trying to randomizes between two floats

Tags: c++

So I have to randomize between two postive floats and two negative floats, the negative floats being [-.010, -0.001] annd the postive floats being [0.05, 0.10]. I cant seem to figure out how to do this as I cant use the % operator like i usually do. This is what my current code looks like:

```
    float randNeg =  rand() % (10.0/-1000.0 + 1.0/-1000.0 - 1) + (1.0/-1000.0);
    float randPos =  rand() % (1.0 / 10.0 + 5.0 / 100.0 - 1) + (5.0 / 100.0);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use [`fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) for decimal modulus. But you're better off with the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header for this.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the facilities available in `<random>`.

Comment: Agreed, If your compiler supports the 2011 standard I recommend you switch to the random library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand()` returns an integer between 0 and RAND_MAX (inclusive), so you can totally map it using something like this:

```
float randFloat(float minVal, float maxVal)
{
    return rand() / (float)RAND_MAX*(maxVal - minVal) + minVal;
}
```

But you should really think about what you actually want to do with this. And be careful with the `rand()` function in general, its primitive, and nowhere near actually random. Attempting to use it for crypto or other sensitive stuff is gonna bite you, hard.